# How to get the socket path in uWebSockets.js?

Tags: uwebsockets

On my server based on uWebSocket.js, I'm using a parameterized path like `/socket/:name`.

How do I capture the actual path used?

For instance, if the socket was connected to `/socket/one`, I'd like to be able to extract the `one` string, or at least get the path so that I can extract the path parameter manually.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out based on [this comment](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js/discussions/339#discussioncomment-172632). Copy-pasting the solution here. You need to use the ws upgrade handler to pass values from the original http request:

```
// pass values from ws upgrade handler
uws.App().ws('/', {
   upgrade: (res, req, context) => {
      res.upgrade(
         { ip: res.getRemoteAddressAsText() }, // 1st argument sets which properties to pass to ws object, in this case ip address
         req.getHeader('sec-websocket-key'),
         req.getHeader('sec-websocket-protocol'),
         req.getHeader('sec-websocket-extensions'), // 3 headers are used to setup websocket
         context // also used to setup websocket
      )
   },
   open: ws => {
      console.log(ws.ip)
   }
})
```